# Repeated Microsoft password reset requests - Should I be concerned?

Tags: password-reset

## Background

Since the middle of last month, I have started receiving multiple Microsoft password reset e-mails a day, sent to my secondary e-mail address, regarding my primary e-mail address.

These e-mails have no phishing-like links in them. I believe them to be a legitimate password reset e-mails. Which means someone is repeatedly trying to reset my password.

There appear to be no (recognizable) attempts to break into my secondary e-mail account.

Both accounts have 2FA enabled, and have randomly generated 30+ character passwords generated by and stored in a password manager. The primary account has enforced 72-day password changes enabled.

## Questions

1. Is it likely the attacks are just trying to guess the 7 digit security code each time? Or is something more sinister likely going on?
2. In cases like this, is there any way to say, "No, I did *not* request such a reset"?

   I'm wary that it is possible that only someone working at Microsoft might be able to answer this. If this **IS** the case, please ignore this part of the question.
3. Should I be concerned about this?

Comment: 1 is likely not possible since they hopefully implement rate limiting. What exactly are you worried about though? Nothing of yours seems to be compromised, except maybe your username is known.

Comment: @multithr3at3d It is a mixture of being worried that there is something more sinister that I am unware of (because it seems weird that someone would be repeatedly requesting resets just to guess the code), and if not, paranoia that they hit on the 1 in 10 million chance of getting the recovery code correct. Almost my entire online identity is linked in some way to that e-mail account, so I'm very scared of it being broken into.

Comment: You say you are affraid they will randomly guess the 2FA code. Do you have reasons to believe that they actually know you password? To send a password reset they don't have to know your password.

Comment: @roy.stultiens It isn't the 2FA code I'm worried about. Microsoft's password reset system is to send an e-mail to a second e-mail account already on record, with a 7 digit number, and then ask the reset-ee that code. It is that that I refer to.

Comment: Ah my bad, in that case you're still fine. Ensure that the secondary email account is also secured (2fa and strong password). The chance of guessing the code is too small for an attacker to succeed.